Session variables are not saved / Session get destroyed - in SiteGround
I implemented a management site in PHP where access to the ID is saved in a session variable ($_SESSION['user']). Still, after I was redirected to another page with a header, the session variable seemed empty on the other page.
I'm sure that the code is written correctly because it works in localhost with XAMPP; in every php page, the session is started at the first line ("session_start();"); the PHP version in SiteGround is the same as the XAMPP version.
At this point I read like 50 blogs and I can't find a solution. I think that the problem is SiteGround because many person in various blogs had the same problem.
I attach the semplified code that I used to try to solve this problem.
INDEX:
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="t">
        <input type="number" name="n">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</html>

LOGIN PAGE:
<?php
    session_start();
    $_POST['t'] = $_SESSION['t'];
    $_POST['p'] = $_SESSION['p'];
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: entered.php");
?>

ENTERED PAGE:
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['t'];
    echo $_SESSION['p'];
?>


On the page where your session variable is empty, what do you get if you do var_dump(session_status()); at the very top of the page, as the first thing?

First of all, use your browser dev tools (network panel), to verify the session ID you received with the redirect response, is the same that gets send with the next request. If that is the case - did you properly exit your script after redirecting (if that is not the last thing you do in there), or is it perhaps still executing any other code after your header() call? Also try if calling session_write_close directly before you redirect, changes anything.

@FiddlingAway the output  of var_dump(session_status()); is "int(1)"

@CBroe I edited the text adding the code so you can watch yourself that I've already done everything you said

Can't tell from looking at the code though, whether you did the first thing I asked for - verify whether the session ID gets transmitted correctly.

I updated the answer to the question that I pinned at the top. Please check the last two bullets in the list.
